# create view with parameter to filter a table

Tags: view

I have a table that contains rows belonging to various users. I want to CREATE A VIEW in a Stored Procedure to work on only the records that belong to me, i.e. CREATE VIEW V1 AS SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE USER_ID = Z.

The user_id z is passed to the Stored Procedure as a Parameter

As I have to carry out many statements on my rows, I do not want to specify "WHERE USER_ID = Z" in all the statements.

However, I find that the CREATE VIEW statement does not accept a parameter.

Is there any solution to create a sub-set of the table containing only the rows that belong to me?

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this approach.

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T2 LIKE T1;
INSERT INTO T2 SELECT * FRON T1 WHERE USER_ID = Z;

I will carry out all the manipulation using T2

At the end of the stored procedure, I will update T1 FROM T2 as follows.

DELETE T1 WHERE USER_ID = Z;
INSERT INTO T1 SELECT * FROM T2;

Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty with the use of the Temporary Table. It does not allow the table to be re-opened as another table under the following format,

SELECT TEMP AS T1 JOIN TEMP AS T2 .....

So I am stuck with the problem.

Hope someone can offer a solution. I cannot understand why VIEW does not allow a parameter to be passed to it, as it seem to be a good approach to work on a sub-set of the table.